# DNS server not responding

Tags: networking, internet, dns

From time to times I have to reboot my Ubuntu 11.04 remote desktop. Once it up and I run Cromium browser with many tabs (20 for example) dns server doesn't respond anymore. At beginning I suspected my ISP, so I replaced my /etc/resolv.conf with following values:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

The result is the same - I can't use browser for ~20 min. because names are not resolved, ping doesn't work either.

Any idea what is blocking?

Comment: When you say _ping doesn't work either_ do you mean IPs also? Or just names? Can you ping `8.8.8.8`?

Comment: I meant just names. During that time I'm able to connect remote machine and some services, like skype, are able to connect to internet (I suppose Skype use IP address).

Comment: did you try removing the first two values?  For me, I completely removed my ISPs DNS entries, and hardcoded (and subsequently write-protected) my list of nameservers... I use `8.8.8.8` and `4.2.2.4` and they work fine.

Comment: The first two are OpenDNS entries, not my ISP.

Comment: regardless if they're your ISP, did you try removing them and just leaving `nameserver 8.8.8.8` just to see what happens?  i just ran a DNS lookup off of `8.8.8.8`, so I know its functioning.

Comment: darn i wasnt fast enough to edit my last comment.  regardless, try this and give us the output: `dig @8.8.8.8 www.ubuntu.com`

Comment: so I changed:  cat /etc/resolv.conf   nameserver 8.8.8.8   and then I ran this: sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart   * Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces   * Reconfiguring network interfaces...

Answer (score 1):

Well, could really be a problem with your ISP DNSs and **maybe** they intercept DNS traffic and route it throurgh their servers...

Try a `dig @8.8.8.8 www.ubuntu.com` and see what happens.

Output should be like:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.ubuntu.com 
; (1 server found) 
;; global options: +cmd 
;; Got answer: 
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54464 
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0 

;; QUESTION SECTION: 
;www.ubuntu.com.      IN  A 

;; ANSWER SECTION: 
www.ubuntu.com.   497 IN  A 91.189.89.88 

;; Query time: 2307 msec 
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) 
;; WHEN: Thu Jul  7 14:23:41 2011 
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48
```

Comment: xxx@xxx:~$ ping www.google.com
^C
xxx@xxx:~$ dig @8.8.8.8 www.ubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.ubuntu.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: Sounds like dns lookups are being blocked somewhere along the line.  Can you ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: x@x:~$ ping 8.8.8.8  
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=54 time=81.8 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=54 time=31.9 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=54 time=29.0 ms  
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=53 time=29.4 ms  
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---  
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms  
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 29.084/43.069/81.809/22.394 ms  
x@x:~$ ping www.google.com  
ping: unknown host www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `dnsmasq` package and configuring it to cache DNS for you.  This should cut down on your DNS queries and may prevent whatever is blocking you from activating.  It could be a DNS rate limit filter somewhere in your chain.

Your `/etc/resolv.conf` for `dnsmasq` should consist of `127.0.0.1`.  I am not sure if the current installer sets this up.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Google's open dns:

so could edit /etc/resolv.conf:

# Googles Public DNS

nameserver 8.8.8.8

nameserver 8.8.4.4

search localdomain