# NetworkManager not populating resolv.conf

Tags: network-manager, dns, resolv.conf

I recently upgraded from `11.10` to `12.04`, and now `NetworkManager` isn't populating `/etc/resolv.conf` when connecting to wireless networks, when it had been working perfectly in `11.10`. I'm not seeing any explicit errors in either the `NetworkManager`, `UI` or in `syslog`. How do I diagnose what's wrong?

**Edit:** If I try to run `resolvconf`, I get the error

> resolvconf: Error: /etc/resolv.conf isn't a symlink, not doing anything.

What should it be, a `symlink` to and/or how do I get `NetworkManager` to populate it? [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html#name-resolution) says the `symlink` should point to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`, but that file does not exist on my system.

Comment: I have tried a combination of the below solutions and then edited `resolv.conf` to include `nameserver 127.0.0.1` because I had this problem about a year ago already and back then I think it had something to do with this line. After a restart the file was overwritten, but not with just comments but a different `nameserver …` line and some other things. Finally, it’s working…

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use following command and answer YES to enable dynamic updates:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Have an old laptop with 12.04 a dead battery that I unplugged by accident. Could ping my home router but not get web pages. Oddly could access other wifi network. This gave me access through home network again.

Comment: The question remains: Why was the symlink missing? This question is being addressed in bug #1000244 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1000244). See comment #66 for my best guesses about the various causes of this problem.

Comment: I had the same problem in 13.04 (out of thin air, NOT a new install), this solution worked for me to.

Comment: I wish there was a 'tip' or 'buy-me-a-beer' button on stack-exchange for thanking people.

Comment: I needed to do this even on Ubuntu 16.04 / Elementary OS 0.4 Loki

Comment: This just happened to me on Ubuntu 16.10. The solution still works, although the dialog strongly suggests an immediate reboot. Edit: It happened out of the blue yesterday, more than a month after the upgrade.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem. Seems that Ubuntu is using a local resolver now. The fastest way to remove that is to comment out the following line in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

For more information, please take a look at [this page](http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/).

Comment: Disabling that line and then restarting NM has no noticeable effect for me. The error still occurs and NM still refuses to populate resolv.conf.

Comment: Thanks for this information! I also had to restart the network manager: `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`.

Answer (score 5):

If /etc/resolv.conf is a file then move it to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf :

```
sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Then create the symlink:

```
sudo ln -s ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: This helps. But easier and more reliable (typos) way for doing that is `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and answer YES.

Comment: This is a great method if you're going to do `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf --frontend=noninteractive` followed up `resolvconf -u`.  If you don't move the file and symlink first, an unattended dpkg-reconfigure will fail because `/etc/resolv.conf` is not a symlink.

Answer (score 1):

Had since a loooong time problems with my laptop, had to

```
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

to be able to make the web work. Found that the resolv.conf was not updated by the network manager, and finally the

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the (right) way of getting rid of `systemd` and uninstalled `systemd-resolved` you probably want this in your `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
dhcp=dhclient
dns=default
rc-manager=resolvconf
systemd-resolved=false
```

Refer to `man NetworkManager.conf` for tweaking the above parameters according to your setup.