# Ubuntu 13.04 DNS problems?

Tags: dns

Anybody experience problems with DNS resolution in Ubuntu 13.04? Ubuntu users are pulling IPs from DHCP (including DNS IP) but DNS doesn't resolve unless we manually change the resolv.conf file. I can see that DHCP sucessfully pulls the correct DNS server IP. Mac and Windows users are not affected.

Comment: Please provide more information by editing the question. Are you using any VPN or something else that is changing the DNS IP. Or is this a one-time setup problem?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/137037/networkmanager-not-populating-resolv-conf#172517

Comment: I have the same problem... but from recently... everything was working one week ago... I checked with the IT office, they say everything is ok (settings), but it does not work correctly.

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf from @user68186 link, worked for me on 13.04

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` resolved my problem with a malfunction DNS. I think my problem originate from using Fortinet SSL VPN client.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Ask Ubuntu way of saying thank you.

Comment: For background see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1000244 and especially the summary in comment #121.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to manually add the DNS nameserver addresses to resolv.conf.  The DHCP linkage to the DNS resolver is not working in Trusty (14.04) on my son's Chrubuntu Acer c720p Chromebook.