# Set network manager dns

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, dns

I have Ubuntu 14.10. When I'm at work I can browse the internet without problems. Now that I'm at home, I can connect, but I'm not able to browse the web.

Some informations:

the output of ifconfig:

```
marcosh@marcoshstudio:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:227 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:227 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:24638 (24.6 KB)  TX bytes:24638 (24.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:19:34:7d:8e:99  
          inet addr:192.168.1.66  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8219:34ff:fe7d:8e99/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:769 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2001 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:87556 (87.5 KB)  TX bytes:234860 (234.8 KB)
```

I am using network-manager, and this is the output of nm-tool:

```
marcosh@marcoshstudio:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [TNCAPC29DB1] -------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        80:19:34:7D:8E:99

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           2 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    ReeKoWLAN:       Infra, 90:94:E4:75:78:B2, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34     WPA WPA2
    TISCALI:         Infra, 9C:97:26:9C:9F:7B, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 90
    *TNCAPC29DB1:    Infra, 58:98:35:C2:9D:B1, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 58    WPA WPA2
    InfostradaWiFi-408829: Infra, 40:CB:A8:8E:EC:C8, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength   45 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.66
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.254

    DNS:             192.168.1.254
    DNS:             8.8.8.8
```

I am worried the somehow the settings in the file /etc/resolv.conf are interfering:

```
marcosh@marcoshstudio:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain mva.local
search mva.local
nameserver 192.168.242.1
```

Is that possible?

I know (since I did that another time) that if I remove and reinstall the network-manager, I will be able to browse from home but not from the office. How can I avoid this and solve my problem once for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I solved it using

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/172517/351927) for more informations

Answer (score 1):

While there might be several possibilities, I suggest we first look at a few of the most likely candidates. If Network Manager is using dnsmasq, as is the default, then /etc/resolv.conf ought to read:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Let's check:

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

The default configuration is:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

As you can see, dnsmasq is enabled. If it is not on your system, we will edit the file to correct it.

Next, click the Network Manager icon, select Edit Connections > Wi-Fi > your_network > IPv4 settings. Be certain that the Method is Automatic (DHCP).

Next, let's edit /etc/resolv.conf:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the file to read:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Finally, restart NM:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Test:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I just solved the problem, see my answer