# How to fix Stale file handle errors?

Tags: filesystem, btrfs, resolv.conf

I receive "Stale file handle" errors (see below) when listing the directory `/etc/resolvconf`

```
ls: cannot access 'resolv.conf.d': Stale file handle
ls: cannot access 'update-libc.d': Stale file handle
ls: cannot access 'update.d': Stale file handle
ls: cannot access 'interface-order': Stale file handle
interface-order resolv.conf.d update.d update-libc.d
```

Also the broken link `/etc/resolv.conf` points to a missing target at `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

Indeed the directory `/run/resolvconf/` only holds an empty file `enable-updates` plus the directory `interface`, which in turn only holds a file called `NetworkManager` containing just the following lines

```
search config
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

I can access my wireless network but not the internet. I receive "unknown host" errors from ping commands.

Upon discovering problems with resolvconf, I followed [this NetworkManager advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137037/networkmanager-not-populating-resolv-conf) from 2012 and ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` which generated `Stale file handle` errors.

My Btrfs filesystem root `/dev/nvme0n1p1n` resides on a Samsung M.2 NVMe 128GB SSD.

Any advice on safe and easy methods to fix a "Stale file handle" will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "btrfs check" yielded many errors including: parent transid verify failed; leaf parent key incorrect; bad block; Errors found in extent allocation tree or chunk allocation; block group has wrong amount of free space; failed to load free space cache for block group; cache appears valid but isnt. However, "badblock" command found zero bad blocks. In the end, I re-installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on the M.2 SSD and this time selected an ext4 filesystem.